# Replacing an item in a dictionary using spread syntax

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx

I have a state data structure in my TypeScript Angular application that includes a `chats` property which is a 'dictionary':

```
export interface State {
  requests: Contact[];
  requestedBy: Contact[];
  chatSummaries: ChatSummary[];
  chats: { [chatId: string]: Chat }
}
```

In my reducer, I would like to replace a chat by key using the spread syntax. I think this is possible, I have a vague memory of doing this before.

My reducer code looks like this:

```
on(fromActions.fetchChatSuccess, (state, {chat}) => {
  // should be able to do this, don't remember the syntax
  return {
    ...state,
    chats: {
      [chat.chatId]: chat,
      ...state.chats
    }
  }
})
```

Can anyone help out with the syntax?

Comment: Note that in TypeScript and JavaScript, these are called "objects", not "dictionaries". It may help if you (or someone else landing on this question later) are searching for help.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your structure with multiple reducers:

```
export const chatsReducer = createReducer({},
  on(fromActions.fetchChatSuccess, 
     (state, {chat}) => {
     return {
       ...state,
       chats: {
         ...state.chats,
         [chat.chatId]: chat,  // <-- You override here the current state of chats
       }
     }
   })
);

export const requestsReducer = createReducer([],
);
export const requestedByReducer = createReducer([],
);
export const chatSummaryReducer = createReducer([],
);

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  requests: requestsReducer;
  requestedBy: requestedByReducer;
  chatSummaries: chatSummaryReducer;
  chats: chatsReducer
};
```